# Powershell Get-Clipboard encoding

Tags: .net, powershell

Copy this word `Привет` from here.

Powershell_Ise.exe:

```
Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html
```

Output:

> ... display: inline !important;
> float:none;">**Привет**/span>!--EndFragment--> /body> /html>

All is ok.

Powershell.exe:

```
Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html
```

Output:

> ... display: inline !important;
> float:none;">**;">РџСЂРёРІРµС‚**/span>!--EndFragment--> /body> /html>

Word broken. Unreadable pack of symbols.

Why this happens? How to fix it? Code is the same in both attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to fix it?

Source: https://psclick.ru/command-list

```
Invoke-WinApi OpenClipboard([IntPtr]::Zero)
$format = Invoke-WinApi -Re IntPtr RegisterClipboardFormat("HTML Format")
$handle = Invoke-WinApi -Re IntPtr GetClipboardData($format)
$size   = Invoke-WinApi -Dll Kernel32 -Re Int GlobalSize($handle)

$buffer = [Byte[]]::new($size)
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($handle, $buffer, 0, $size)
Invoke-WinApi CloseClipboard

[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you decompile and search for the function for the cmdlet, and look at the way it generates the output:

```
.\ILSpy.exe (Get-Command Get-Clipboard).DLL
```

You'll get:

```
// System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

private static void GetClipboardContentForHtml(StringBuilder sbContent, out MemoryStream utf8Stream)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sbContent.ToString());
    byte[] array = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, bytes);
    int num = 135 + array.Length;
    int num2 = num + 36;
    string value = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Version:1.0\r\nStartHTML:00000097\r\nEndHTML:{0}\r\nStartFragment:00000133\r\nEndFragment:{1}\r\n", new object[2]
    {
        num2.ToString("00000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        num.ToString("00000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    }) + "<HTML>\r\n<BODY>\r\n<!--StartFragment-->";
    sbContent.Insert(0, value);
    sbContent.Append("\r\n<!--EndFragment-->\r\n</BODY>\r\n</HTML>");
    bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sbContent.ToString());
    array = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, bytes);
    utf8Stream = new MemoryStream(num2 + 1);
    utf8Stream.Write(array, 0, num2);
    utf8Stream.WriteByte(0);
}
```

I **think** that it's by design? If I recall correctly, HTML defaults to UTF-8, so specifically asking for **-TextFormatType Html** converts the Unicode (UTF-16 LE) value to UTF-8.

Furthermore, **Get-Clipboard -Raw** does show the Unicode value correctly in a regular non-ISE instance.